Como leer los datos de Input Dinámicas
Estoy teniendo problemas para leer los datos ingresados en Inputs dinamicos. Mi idea es que el usuario pueda crear la cantidad de inputs que necesite y luego poder almacenarlos en una base de dato. El problema que tengo es que nose como leer o capturar cada unos de los datos ingresados en casa input.
//Este es el Codigo que utilizo para crear los Imput Dinamcos
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".removeButton").on("click", removeRow);
    $(".addButton").on("click", addRow);
});

function addRow(event) {
    var rowId = $(event.target).attr("data-row-id");
    var $row = $("#" + rowId);
    var $newRow = $row.clone(true, true);
    
    var newId = "row_" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
    
    $newRow.attr("id", newId);
    
    $newRow.find(".removeButton").attr("data-row-id", newId);
    $newRow.find(".addButton").attr("data-row-id", newId);
    $newRow.find("input").val("");
    
    $row.after($newRow);
}

function removeRow(event) {
    var rowId = $(event.target).attr("data-row-id");
    var $row = $("#" + rowId);
    
    $row.remove();
}

</script>

//Este es el codigo que utilizo para saber la cantidad de inputs creados
<script>
function prueba(){
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("text").length;
var inp = document.querySelectorAll('.texto');
console.log("Hay " + divs + " elementos");


for(var i = 0; i < divs; i++){
    alert("Hay " + divs + " elementos");
    
    }
}
</script>

//Nose como ingresar a cada input para capturar su valor

En la pregunta no termina de quedar claro cuál es el problema. Puedes leer los inputs con los valores con JavaScript, ¿qué es lo que está bloqueando que captures su valor? Sería ideal que añadieses una descripción más detallada del problema y, a ser posible, un [mcve] para que podamos ver el código funcionando (p.e. haces referencia a las clases "text" y "texto" para leer los campos, pero esas clases no aparece en ningún otro sitio, ¿qué es?) Lee [ask] para más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas.

Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de todos los inputs de todos los elementos que se han clonado:
Primero, en la función addRow agregale una clase en común a los clones $newRow para que despues sa facil seleccionarlos y al input pues igual asociale el newId de pasada (como id).
function addRow(event) {

    //código original de la función...

    $newRow.find("input").attr("id", newId); //le pones el id al input (NO 'imput')
    $newRow.classList.add('fila-clonada') //antes de colocar $newRow le agregas la clase
    $row.after($newRow);

    //final del código de la función
}

Luego con otra función se extraen los valores, por ejemplo:
function getValoresInputsTodos(){

    let inputsTodos = document.getElementsByClassName['fila-clonada'];
    let valores = [];

    Array.from(inputsTodos).forEach(input => {
        valores.push({"input_id": input.id, "valor": input.value});
    });

    return valores; //Regresa un array de objetos [{}]
}

y así los obtienes: let valoresDeTodosLosInputsClonados = getValoresInputsTodos();
